# Can I include nominal predictor variables in ordinal regression?

Tags: regression, ordinal-data, binary-data, predictor, categorical-data

I am in the process of performing ordinal regression on a large data set that measures different types of variables (nominal, ordinal, continuous). My outcome variable is ordinal, hence the ordinal regression. My question is; can I include nominal data (e.g. a binary coded variable representing a 'yes/no' response) as a predictor variable?

Comment: Yes you can. They are interpreted the same as they would be in other regression models.